# PL-SQL: why does a dynamic statement using bind-variable input not work?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create and execute a dynamic SQL statement (using Oracle PL/SQL) and when things didn't work I condensed it to the below two code snippets:

My understanding was that the following two statements would be equivalent (table_name, row_name and row_value are all VARCHAR2 strings):

```
query_statement VARCHAR2(1000);

    -- variant a:
        query_statement := 'select * from ' || table_name || ' where ' || row_name || ' = ' || row_value;
        dbms_output.put_line('query="' || query_statement || '"');        
        execute immediate (query_statement);

    -- variant b:
        query_statement := 'select * from :table where :row = :value';
        dbms_output.put_line('query="' || query_statement || '"');        
        execute immediate (query_statement) using table_name, row_name, row_value;
```

But not so! The first variant works fine, the second always fails with an error:

> ** An error was encountered: -903 ORA-00903: invalid table name

From a readability point of view I would prefer variant b but I don't get, why that second variant fails and why the table_name is flagged as wrong. After all that very same name obviously works in variant a. The emitted queries also looks identical to me - of course modulo the fact that the second string still contains placeholders only while the first string contains already concrete values.

Could some kind soul shed some light on this? Why is variant b not working? What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure where this is documented exactly, but bind variables are for parameters like `where cheese_type = :b1` where the same query can be run for different values, not for structural components that would result in different queries altogether like `where :b1 :b2 :b3` or `:b1 :b2 :b3 :b4`. Dynamic SQL is a quite different thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a bind variable as a [`table_reference`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6). As documented in the link, the `table_reference` must be static part of the statement.

```
 select * from :table  -- ILLEGAL
```

Contrary to that the usage in the `WHERE` clause is allowed

```
 where :row = :value  -- LEGAL, but questionable
```

but it doesn't do what you expect. The `where`clause returns TRUE, if both bind variables passed are same.
I.e. it is equivalent to

```
 where 'name' = 'xxxx'
```

and **not** to

```
 where name = 'xxxx'
```

Comment: Thanks William Robertson, Marmite Bomber and XING for responding and clarifying this! This was very helpful! Sorry, that I can accept only one of your responses as accepted answer!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @William, usage of bind variable as `Tablename` is prohibited. On similar lines, you cannot use bind variables as `Column Names` and `Order By` clause as well.

Although this is not documented anywhere but its important to note that replacing these ordinal notation affects the `execution plan`.